# OutOfMemoryError when loading 100MB file, despite 550MB heap

Tags: java, memory, out-of-memory, heap-memory

following problem:

1. I start my developed program (-Xmx550M)
2. I load a 90 MB file

This loading is the peak of the used heap in the picture below. After this, the heap size increases from 130 to 500 MB, although only 110 MB are needed.

Well ok, no problem, annoying, but ok. But if I now start a save process (which needs ~100 MB) the Java VM crashes with the java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space exception.

[image: Heap Size and Used Heap (-Xmx550M)]

If I started the application with 750 MB heap size, it works fine. You see the short peak and it works fine:
[image: Heap Size and Used Heap (-Xmx750M)]

Now my question: Why the hell do I get an OutOfMemoryError with 550 MB Heap Size? The application only needs 400 MB (at the highest peak)!

I do not know how to fix that :(

Please help me!

Comment: Side question: How did you get those pretty pictures?

Comment: @thatidiotguy I am using the Netbeans Profiler ;)

Comment: Ahhhh, well now I have to find out if Eclipse offers me such a feature.

Comment: @Nambari I do not understand what you meen. In the upper picture one can see that my application uses ~110MB and the heap size is ~500 MB. When I save, the used heap grows uo to 400 MB (lower pic). So why isn't it working with a heap of ~500 MB?

Comment: How are you loading the file?  If you're not loading it as bytes, but as a `String`, the encoding and decoding overhead (and the overhead of UTF-16 characters) might cause this kind of peak.

Comment: I think this is a case for a [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Presumably, the estimate of the memory needed is less than the actual memory. Without an example, it is difficult to say anything useful about the reason for the difference.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman I am loading it as bytes, there are no Strings

Comment: @Ph3n1x I still think you should run some kind of sophisticated memory / GC analyzer, to gain more info and progress this thing.

Comment: @Esailija I am not deep into the java memory management and therfore I just hoped someone here could help me ;-)

Comment: @Ph3n1x yeah but there is only so much people can tell you just from those two graphs, with more info you have a better chance

Comment: *Why* are you loading a 90MB file? Don't read large files into memory. It wastes both time and space. You should process it as you read it.

Answer (score 1):

If you load 100Mb file, it doesn't yet mean that structures, used for this file in memory occupy 100M. For instance, if you have String, you also have 4 byte overhead for its length.

Comment: +1 If the program runs fine with a heap of 750 MB but not with 550 MB, it means it need more than 550 MB and the way the 400 MB requirement was calculated was flawed.  You can't use the graph to determine the maximum as this only shows how much was used a little time before it failed.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey the lower graph shows the run with 750 MB where it works fine. I repeated it some times and the used heap is always ~400 MB at save. My conclusion: the application needs 400 MB at most. But with 550 MB heap it crashes...

Comment: I am loading it as bytes, there are no Strings

Comment: Are you using any other command line options which impact the size of the generations? For example if you have a minimum or maximum newsize you may find you cannot use all the memory for one large array as it will not fit into either the eden or old gen spaces, even though you have enough memory in total.

Answer (score 1):

The data is sampled. Just before it failed it was using 400 MB, and then some time later it tried to use more memory e.g. 600 MB but this didn't show because by the time the next sample was taken the OOME had happened and you usage is now much lower.

In short, your program can use memory faster than you can see in the graphs.

Comment: The lower graph shows the run with 750 MB where it works fine. I repeated it some times and the used heap is always ~400 MB at save. My conclusion: the application needs 400 MB at most. But with 550 MB heap it crashes...

Comment: @Ph3n1x I think the point is that even a very really brief phase that needs more than 550 MB would cause the failure. A sampled report would not be likely to see it unless the high memory use persists for a significant fraction of the sampling interval.

Comment: You also have to consider that your memory is divided into four regions, one eden, two survivor and one old gen. If you try to allocate a large object you can find the JVM is unable to resize you various regions so the large object will fit into any one of them.  This is made more likely if you use other GC related options which mean the JVM isn't free to change the sizes as it might.